# J2ME Label Problem

Tags: java, java-me

any one know how to change the label side of ChoiceGroup or TextField.( i mean default label come before the TextField. i need to bring label after the TextField)
sorry for my bad English i guess you guys understand the my problem.

Comment: which framework you are using ?

Comment: Just a suggestion: use LWUIT (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/); its far more flexible and powerful than default J2ME lcdui classes.

Comment: did LWUIT work in every device that support  CLDC 1.1 MIDP 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no direct support in lcdui classes for your requirement, I would suggest try exploring [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Using standard controls is bad idea at all. Try to use CustomItem, third-party controls or create your own.